# N queens recursive method 1d array

Tags: java, n-queens

I am unsure how to write this method. positionQueens(0) is supposed to place a queen in the first row and then call itself with positionQueens(1) and place into next row. If it's now able to place in any spot on a row it should backtrack to previous row and check to place previous queen in a new spot.

```
private void positionQueens(int row){
    for (int col = 0; col < row; col++){
        if(legal(row,col)){
            queens[row] = col;
        }
        else {
            positionQueens(row+1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my method to check whether its legal to place queen in n row, column

```
 private boolean legal(int row, int col){
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        if ((queens[i] == col) || (Math.abs(i-row)==Math.abs(queens[i]-col))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn what kinds of questions are appropriate for this site.  If you can [edit] your question to fit the requirements of this site, please do so.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: You can find a solution for N queens Problem in different programming languages at https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/n-queen-problem-backtracking-3/